# How can I get the "last one" from the list after excluding a specific nth elements from the list?

Tags: python

**Summary:** I want to get the "element" the would be left in the list after excluding elements. I will explain below how I intended to do that.

Let us say I have list called "my_list" and a given x = 4

```
    x = 4
    my_list = ["apple", "banana", "candy", "durian", "elephant", "flower"]
```

if x = 4, then I want to exclude the 4th element in the list which is the "durian". (or perhaps you could say the 3rd index). So the new list would be:

```
    x = 4
    my_list = ["apple", "banana", "candy", "elephant", "flower"]
```

After I excluded that element, I want to continue counting "4", but instead of counting again from the start (apple), I will start at "elephant" because it is beside the one I excluded. (So, in short, it is just continuous counting without going back to the start). So if this is the case, and I count the 4th element again starting from "elephant"... The 4th element would be "banana". (Note: After you reached "flower" you will continue it at "apple").

So if the 4th element is the "banana", I am going to exclude it again and the new list would be:

```
    x = 4
    my_list = ["apple", "candy", "elephant", "flower"]
```

Then, I will repeat the same process again until the length of "my_list" is equal to "1".

So, resuming the process... I will continue counting from "candy". (because it is beside "banana"). And the 4th element for this time is "apple". Then the new list would be:

```
    x = 4
    my_list = ["candy", "elephant", "flower"]
```

So, after doing the same mechanics (counting from "candy"), the new list would be:

```
    x = 4
    my_list = ["elephant", "flower"]
```

So, for the last time (counting from "elephant"), the new and final list would be:

```
    x = 4
    my_list = ["elephant"]
```

This time, the length of the list is now equal to one. This is how I want my program to work. I want to get the "elephant" or the one will be left after the process. I am new to python so I hope you can help me to program this. I have been stuck in this problem for days and I cannot think of any ideas anymore. Please help me to code this.

Comment: @Santhosh Sorry, I do not know what circular linked list is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` to good effect here in order to keep circling around the shrinking list:

```
i = 0
x = 4
while my_list:
    i = (i+x-1) % len(my_list)
    my_list.pop(i)
    print(my_list)

'durian'
['apple', 'banana', 'candy', 'elephant', 'flower']
'banana'
['apple', 'candy', 'elephant', 'flower']
'apple'
['candy', 'elephant', 'flower']
'candy'
['elephant', 'flower']
'flower'
['elephant']
'elephant'
[]
```

Of course, there are better data structures than a list (with its `O(n)` removal from the middle), but this just shows the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque
x = 4
my_list = ["apple", "banana", "candy", "durian", "elephant", "flower"]

my_deque = deque(my_list)
while len(my_deque) > 1:
    my_deque.rotate(-x)
    print(my_deque.pop())
print(my_deque)
```

Comment: That's much better algorithmically and more elegant! +1

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#Solution) and has an explicit solution for k=2 but requires recursion for k >=4:

With n the total number of elements and k the count of each step, we denote f(n,k) the survivor. Then the recursion formula is ((f(n-1,k) + k - 1)mod n) + 1.

Let's code this using recurion!

```
import numpy as np


def josephus(n, k):
    if n == 1 or k == 1:
        return 1
    if k == 2:
        return 2*(n - 2 ** (np.floor(np.log2(n)))) - 1  # Explicit solution for k = 2
    return ((josephus(n - 1, k) + k - 1) % n) + 1 

josephus(6, 4)
# The output is 5 which is the position of 'elephant' in your list
```