# Solution of Josephus problem with negative count

Tags: python, algorithm, josephus

I would like to find the simplest algorithm for the general Josephus problem, i.e. *with a count in any direction*.
The combined "recursive-list" algorithm is taken as a basis (Python).
It works well with positive shift and starts well with negative, but then something goes wrong.

```
def add(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return 1
    return -1


def josephus(arr, start, shift):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    else:
        start = (start + shift - add(shift)) % len(arr)
        arr.pop(start)
        print(arr)
        return josephus(arr, start, shift)

size = int(input())
people = list(range(1, size + 1))
start = int(input()) - 1
shift = int(input())
print(people)
josephus(people, start, shift)
```

Adding several "if" statements could help, but I would not like to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by a count in any direction? If you want to circle in the other direction you can just reorder your input array? As for the implementation there is BrutusForcus' answer below or mine with the explicit solution for k = 2 :https://stackoverflow.com/a/69492418/13756061.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your `add()` function. So you only want to shift by +1 or -1, never by any other number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the different behaviour with negative values is that *after* executing `arr.pop(start)`, the value at the `start` index (modulo the new size) will always be the *next* element in "clockwise" (right) direction.

This effect should be mirrored when the shift is negative.

So when `shift` is negative, subtract one from `start` after executing the `pop`:

```
    arr.pop(start)
    if shift < 0: 
        start -= 1
```